# CachedRowset acceptChanges not working after insert opertion

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am using MySQL database and I have a table `Employee` with 2 columns: `Id` (Int; Primary Key) and `Name` (String). I have written some code to insert a row into the `Employee` table, but the `acceptChanges` is not working and the code stops at `acceptChanges`. The code is as follows :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;

public class InsertSynchronizer {

    static CachedRowSet crs = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "");
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            RowSetFactory myRowSetFactory = null;
            myRowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            crs = myRowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
            crs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
            crs.setUsername("root");
            crs.setPassword("");
            crs.setConcurrency(CachedRowSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            crs.setCommand("select * from employee");
            crs.execute();
            while (crs.next()) {
                System.out.println(crs.getString("Name"));
            }

            // Inserting rows
            crs.moveToInsertRow();
            crs.updateInt("Id", 5);
            crs.updateString("Name", "E");
            crs.insertRow();

            //Thread.sleep(60000);
            crs.acceptChanges(c); // Updating Data Sources

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `crs.moveToCurrentRow()` have to be added after  `crs.insertRow()` and before `crs.acceptChanges(c)`

For example:

```
 // Inserting rows
crs.moveToInsertRow();
crs.updateInt("Id", 5);
crs.updateString("Name", "E");
crs.insertRow();
crs.moveToCurrentRow(); // NEW STATEMENT
crs.acceptChanges(c); // Updating Data Sources
```

For more information visit: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html#inserting-and-deleting-rows

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. But I haven't understood why that statement was required. If you don't mind, can you explain the significance of that statement ?

Comment: When you called moveToInsertRow you cannot accept changes, you have to step back to remembered position. Method moveToCurrentRow moves the cursor to the row where the cursor was on, when the method moveToInsertRow was called.

Comment: For example,you can insert row while you are iterating through the RowSet: while (crs.next()) {/*insert the row here*/}. So if you do not move back to the current row you can't go further, because a row for inserting is not a part of your RowSet. Calling moveToInsertRow is similar to entering some special room for doing something, than you must leave the room to continue the iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmytro. That explained everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You will find it helpful to print out all the information regarding the Exception. If you catch an SQLException instead of the generic Exception (in general you should be catching specific Exceptions), you will get access to more information, including the [SQL state and error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-error-sqlstates.html).

I believe in this case you will find it is an error relating to the fact that the connection is set to automatically commit changes. I believe the CachedRowSet is making its own Connection when you initialise and execute its command. It doesn't know about the Connection "c" you've created until you pass it to acceptChanges. This, I assume, means that crs' connection has autoCommit set to true in the meantime.

Try adding ?relaxAutoCommit=true to your url string as follows:

```
crs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?relaxAutoCommit=true");
```

You won't need to pass it a Connection to accept changes, as it will have its own. In fact, you won't need to create the other Connection, which will remain open the whole time. The whole point of a CachedRowSet is that you don't keep the connection open while you make changes.

Comment: It isin't working. Can you modify my code to reflect exactly how would it work ? May be I am doind something incorrect.

Comment: I think `relaxAutoCommit` is for something else. I get your idea and agree with it, but in my case it also didn't help. From what I read, it's for versions of MySQL that do not support transactions (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-connp-props-miscellaneous.html)